# INotifyPropertyChanged with a List

Tags: c#, uwp, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

What is the correct way to use INotifyPropertyChanged with a List?

I have a CertInfo class that is a class of certifications:

```
    namespace ResumeApp
{
    public class CertInfo
    {
        public DateTime AcquiredDate { get; set; }
        public String Certification { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public CertInfo()
        {}

        public CertInfo(DateTime acquiredDate, String cert, bool enabled, int userId)
        {
            this.AcquiredDate = acquiredDate;
            this.Certification = cert;
            this.Enabled = enabled;
            this.UserId = userId;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a Resume class that is INotifyPropertyChanged. I'm not sure about how to use the Notify with a List. Here is my Resume class:

```
    namespace ResumeApp
{
    public class Resume : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private PersonalInfo personal;
        private int userId;
        private ObservableCollection<CertInfo> certList;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public Resume()
        {
            personal = new PersonalInfo();
            userId = 0;
            certList = new ObservableCollection<CertInfo>();
        }

        public PersonalInfo Personal
        {
            get { return personal; }
            set
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    personal = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Personal");
                }
            }
        }

        public int UserId
        {
            get { return userId; }
            set
            {
                if (value != 0)
                {
                    userId = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("UserId");
                }
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<CertInfo> CertList
        {
            get { return certList; }
            set
            {
                if(value != null)
                {
                    certList = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CertList");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is that correct?

Thanks

Comment: The value of the CertList property is a reference to an ObservableCollection instance. Whenever that value changed invoke PropertyChanged and there is no difference to other properties

Comment: Do you know you won't get a notification if a property of a ResumeApp instance changed?

Comment: It will be a UWP app. Should I create a ResumeController and let the notification inside this controller? Then, bind my xaml DataContext to the controller?

Comment: If you need that notifications (for binding) implement INotifyPropertyChanged on ResumeApp

Comment: It's how I'm doing right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be correct, if you intend to change the actual instance of `ObservableCollection<CertInfo>` within an instance of `Resume`.

However, in most cases it is absolutely sufficient to declare this type of association with a get-only property, as the collection itself really never changes, only elements of it (add / remove).`ObservableCollection<T>` itself implements [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx), which notifies the UI about these modifications.

you could strip down the CertList-Property to this declaration:

```
public ObservableCollection<CertInfo> CertList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<CertInfo>();
```

To pre-initialize an instance with a given collection, i would recommend the following constructors:

```
public Resume(ObservableCollection<CertInfo> certList) {
  //null-checks ommited
  CertList = certlist;
  //more initialization
  userId = 0;

}
public Resume(IEnumerable<CertInfo> certList) : this (new ObservableCollection(certlist) {

}
public Resume() : this(new ObservableCollection<CertInfo>()) {
}
```

Comment: BTW ObservableCollection implements INotifyPropertyChanged too

Comment: Thank you. How can I initialize Resume passing a list of CertInfo to my ObservableCollection CertList?

Comment: Just define an appropriate Constructor, passing in the collection.
The shortened readonly property is settable in constructors, also.

Comment: and if you ever need to change the whole collection outside of constructors, just fire the PropertyChanged-Event, as you did in your initial example.

Comment: Thanks. ObservableCollection<CertInfo> certList accept List<CertInfo> type?

Comment: As ObservableCollection<T> itself defines a constructor that accepts IEnumerable<T>, the choice is up to you, or leave it "open" as IEnumerable<CertInfo>, so the caller has to choose.

It could be an instance of ObservableCollection<T>, which you just set in your property

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful. BTW, do I need to set  INotifyCollectionChanged in my CertInfo class?

Comment: no need for that - only if you would implement a collection. And if so, deriving from ObservableCollection<T> would be sufficient in most cases.